# 12 AWG galvanized steel high tensile wire okay for running 12 volt 7 A DC?

Tags: ground, 12v, copper, wire-size

I need to run 12 VDC about 50' along a fence that already has several 12 gauge galvanized steel wires running on it. It is going to be pulling less than 7 A at most.  I can make sure the lines are not touching, but they are in the air and exposed to the elements. Will this work? and will I see significant voltage drop (greater than 5%)?  My battery is a 115 Ah deep cycle lead-acid and I have a 12 V appliance that needs at least 11.5 V that consume about 4 A.

Also, dumb question I want to ask, but does negative line need to run all the way back to the battery? and if so, can that touch metal t-posts posts that are 2' in the ground?  I am wondering if metal the fence itself was connected to the negative battery lead and my hot (+) were copper, insulated and direct would this help significantly?

Comment: There's always a voltage drop so that question is easily answered.

Comment: okay :)  clarified rephrased the question.  I have an appliance that needs 11.5v or more and I would be seriously cutting the batteries range.

Comment: you have all of the components ... put them together and see .... you only need to keep te `+` and `-` separated ... perhaps one of the conductors should be insulated to prevent accidental shorting

Comment: Current only runs in a loop; so yes you need both wires. For just a battery and two wires, either of those can touch the ground with no ill effects. Consider the load however; is it's negative connected to the chassis? Use a 5A fuse at the battery. If you can run rigid metal conduit along the fence, regular "romex" building wire will work fine and be protected from the elements, treefall, kids, etc.

Comment: The voltage drop is motor current multiplied by total length of wire (distance between battery and motor X2) mutiplied wire resistance per unit length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the resistivity of 12 AWG wire [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge), then it runs at about 5 mΩ per metre. If you look up the resistivity of various steel alloys [Kaye and Laby](https://web.archive.org/web/20190511040354/http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_6/2_6_1.html) you'll see that carbon steel is about 10x the resistivity of copper, or about 50 mΩ per metre.

50' is about 15 m, or 30 m there and back. 30 * 50 mΩ = 1.5 Ω, which at 7 A will drop 7*1.5 = 10.5 V.

That means if you short circuit the far end, even then you won't draw much more than 7 A. You don't stand a snowball in Hades chance of running 12 V at that current down your steel wires.

Now depending on where you want to spend your money, you could run copper wires of a slightly heavier gauge along your fence, or you could boost the voltage at the sending end, say to 48 V as being a common voltage for converters and around the maximum 'touch safe' voltage recognised by most authorities, and step it back down again at the receiving end. This reduces your current by a factor of four, and so the reduced voltage drop of <3 V is now compared to a much higher voltage, so proportionately less loss.

Answer (score 1):

The conductivity of metals varies about 10:1.

silver is the most conductive.

Copper is about 1/2 of silver

Tungsten is about 1/10 of silver.

Iron/steel ..... look it up, get the mils (diameter, or cross sectional area) and run Ohms Law.

Since you want DC, you need not be concerned with the time constant of the steel/iron atoms; just be aware that iron_derived wirings are **SLOW** to allow changes in current, because of the long delays in penetrating the atoms and causing the electron orbits to tilt in ways (that tilting does requires energy from the 7 Ampere current) that mutually align the orbits among atoms. That is what IRON does.

Thus you need substantial charge storage at the FAR END, at the LOAD end, of the wiring.

That simple steel "wire" will be many milliHenries of energy storage, and will be SLOW to allow changes.

To compensate for I * R voltage drop, you might set the 12 volts to 12.5 volts, if adjustable.

======================================

This link provides a table (on the far right column) of Relative Permeabiility.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/permeability-d_1923.html

The speed is 1/sqrt(Relative Permeability).

For #12 copper --- 1/8 inch or so --- expect about 0.1 second to settle to full voltage at the far end.

For pure iron, given the MUr --- Relative Permeability --- of 200,000, you should expect about 50 seconds. Thus the TURNON will be slow.

You are not using PURE IRON, so will be much faster.

Comment: What is the physical parameter that characterizes this slowness compared to other materials?